# Validation in ASP.NET with Getter & Setter

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, boolean

I am trying to do a validation when user input is correct, I used a label with black text to display. On the contrary, when user input is incorrect, I display the error message in another label with red text in ASP.NET. It's a 3 tier program. Here is the codes in my presentation layer:

```
    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolsBLL calcBMI = new ToolsBLL();
    lbl_result.Text = "";
    lbl_invalid.Text = "";
    if (calcBMI.Valid == true)
    { 
        lbl_result.Text = calcBMI.calcBMI(tb_height.Text, tb_weight.Text);
    }
    else if (calcBMI.Valid == false)
    {
        lbl_invalid.Text = calcBMI.calcBMI(tb_height.Text, tb_weight.Text);
    }

}
```

It will call the getter and setter which named Valid in BusinessLogicLayer to check whether the input is valid. And here is the codes in my BusinessLogicLayer:

```
    public static Boolean valid;
    public Boolean Valid
    {
        get { return valid; }
        set { valid = value; }
    }

    public string calcBMI(string sheight, string sweight)
    {
        decimal height = 0;
        decimal weight = 0;
        string bmiResultDesc = "";
        decimal bmi = 0;
        ToolsBLL.valid = true;

        if (sheight == "" && sweight == "")
        {
            ToolsBLL.valid = false;
            bmiResultDesc = "Height/Weight cannot be blank.";  
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                height = decimal.Parse(sheight);
                weight = decimal.Parse(sweight);
            }
            catch
            {
                ToolsBLL.valid = false;
                bmiResultDesc = "Height/Weight must be in numeric.";
            }
        }

        if (bmiResultDesc == "")
        {
            if (height <= 0)
            {
                ToolsBLL.valid = false;
                bmiResultDesc = "Invalid height";
            }
            else if (weight <= 0)
            {
                ToolsBLL.valid = false;
                bmiResultDesc = "Invalid weight";
            }
            else
            {
                BMICalculator.BMICalculator bmiCalc = new BMICalculator.BMICalculator();
                bmi = bmiCalc.computeBMI(height, weight);
                if (bmi <= 0)
                {
                    ToolsBLL.valid = false;
                    bmiResultDesc = "Error in consuming web services.";                   
                }
                else
                {
                    ToolsBLL.valid = true;
                    bmiResultDesc = "Your BMI is " + bmi.ToString();  
                }
            }

        }
        return bmiResultDesc;
    }
```

I used a getter and setter to set for value for boolean. I am not sure if I am doing in the correct way or not because my BMICalculator behaves strange. For example, when I type in correct input, sometimes it shows in black but sometimes it shows in red. I have no idea why is it so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (calcBMI.Valid == true)
{ 
    lbl_result.Text = calcBMI.calcBMI(tb_height.Text, tb_weight.Text);
    lbl_result.ForeColor = Color.Black;

}
else if (calcBMI.Valid == false)
{

    lbl_result.Text = "Your input is invalid";
    lbl_result.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Nope, what I am trying to do is display one label for each time of user input. Not both at once

Comment: Ok.  But then, why are you using two different labels in your code?  Just use 1 and change its color and text.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that? I thought only can change the font color via property?

Comment: See edited version above.  By the looks of some comments, you might have an actual validation issue.  In fact, I think they are correct.  You are not running the validation METHOD before evaluating the Valid PROPERTY.

Comment: It just keep returning me the invalid one although I typed in valid inputs. Nevermind, I think I should reformat all my codes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get up-to-date information about validity of something, you should check validity when you need it instead of reading some property thatsay you about validity in past. So just add method Validate and check validation in it before you perform calculations. 
And it will be good idea to use validation attributes to check if height and weight is numeric and is.